# c# Recursive model with what level you are on

Tags: c#

Say you have a simplified tree like this

- Level 1 item

  - Level 2 item
  - Level 2 item

    - Level 3 item
- Level 1 item
- Level 1 item

  - Level 2 item

    - Level 3 item
    - Level 3 item
  - Level 2 item

I have this code which works fine and loops through it and creates a list with all the items and which level they are on. But this will only work with 3 levels and it would be nice if this could work with any levels and less repeated code.

```
public IEnumerable<Model> GetItems(string rootLink) {
    foreach (var node1 in loadItems(rootLink) {
       yield return new Model(node1, level: 1);

       foreach (var node2 in loadItems(node1.link) {
           yield return new Model(node2 , level: 2);  
 
           foreach (var node3 in loadItems(node2.link) {
               yield return new Model(node3 , level: 3);  
           }
       }
    }
}
```

So I am wondering if I can make this a recursive function instead. I tried with something like this, but the level will be wrong here since I am just adding to it.

```
public IEnumerable<Model> GetItems(string link, int level = 1)
{
    foreach (var node in loadItems(link))
    {
        yield return new Model(category, level);

        foreach (var subNode in GetItems(category.link, level++))
        {
            yield return subNode;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you _want_ the solution to be recursive or are iterative solutions ok, too?

Comment: You shouldn't use `level++` since that will add for every iteration of the `foreach` loop. Instead just pass in `level + 1`

Comment: @stibay - Your pseudo code is full of syntax errors. Can you please post a [mcve]? Getting it to work then should be a breeze.

Comment: And, of course, if your source data can be in standard C# code, that would be awsome.

Comment: Is it really that many syntax errors? Just simplified it abit, but yea, just chaging from level++ to level + 1 in the recursive function works perfect for me.

Comment: @stibay - I tried to recreate the missing code - the class and the methods you're calling. It just didn't have consistency. I could not remove the syntax errors without modifying your code. I think you over simplified.

Comment: @stibay - Can you please provide the actual code for your classes, including the methods, and a sample source set of data as C# code?

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but an iterative approach would look something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Model> GetItems(string rootLink) 
{
    // Setup a work queue
    var queue = new Queue<Item>();
    // Start with the root node
    foreach(var level1 in loadItems(rootLink))
        queue.Enqueue(new Item(level1, 1));

    while(queue.Count > 0)
    {
        var current = queue.Dequeue();
        yield return new Model(current.Node, current.Level);

        // Enqueue child-nodes of the current node if any
        foreach( var child in loadItems(current.Node.link))
            queue.Enqueue(new Item(child, current.Level+1);
    }
}

private record Item(YourType Node, int Level);
```